# Model for repeated measures taken on the same occasion?

Tags: clustering, mixed-model, least-squares, multilevel-analysis

I have been studying mixed effects models and I read that multiple measurements such as three judges rate the taste of a food item or  weigh a mouse three times during the same measurement occasion are not considered true repeated measures data. So, mixed models for repeated measures can not be applied to such data. So how does such data are studied where there are multiple measurements of dependent and independent variables?

Can pooled OLS regression be used on these variables, given that it is likely that the multiple observations for a subject will be correlated?

I am stuck with this issue for a long time and any help is welcome.

**Following is the design of the study:**

This is a **hypothetical** medical situation to describe my problem. CO2 has an effect on pH in the blood. I need to assess the effect of age and species type on pH  while controlling for the CO2 present in the blood of an animal Monkey. The sample size of animals is 100 consisting of various unequal proportions of ages and species.

There is an equipment Tester that can measure CO2 and pH in the blood. This equipment is available in 10 brands (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,and J). All the brands of Tester suffer from imprecision and show variability in the measurements of CO2 and pH in the blood. So, both  CO2 and pH is measured using all the 10 brands. So, CO2 and pH is measured using Tester A for the monkey 1. Then CO2 and pH is measured again using Tester B for monkey 1. This process is repeated 10 times. So, there are total 10 observations for monkey 1 taken using Tester A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,and J on the same occasion. It is to be noted that all the 10 measurements of CO2 and pH for monkey 1 shall be correlated.This process is done for all the monkeys in the sample. Thus, there `10 repetitions * 100 monkeys` observations for CO2 as well as pH.

Age and species type also has an effect on CO2 presence in the blood. I want to estimate two different models.

- One model where I estimate the effect of age and species on pH while
  controlling for CO2
- one model where I estimate the effect of age and species on pH while
  controlling for CO2 while taking account of the effect of age and
  species on CO2 (that is determinants also effect control variable.)

Comment: Is it a valid idea to use OLS regression in this case?

Comment: Can you provide us with more details about the study design?

Comment: @JonB Please see details regarding study design.